# React Star Rating Function: Image Not Displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, image

Sincerest apologies to those who spent time and energy answering my previous question.  I originally assumed I wasn't going to get help so I started working on it myself.  I got pretty far so I'd rather not rebuild what I've done from the ground up.

This react component is a row of stars.  When the user clicks a star, it and all previous stars go from empty to full. If star 2 is clicked, both star 1 and 2 become full, etc. This ALMOST works.  Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Starset0 extends Component {



rate = event => {
    const {id} = event.target;

    console.log("You clicked: " + id);
    var i;

    for (i = 1; i < parseFloat(id) + 1; i++) { 
console.log("I should change the following: " + i);
document.getElementById(i).setAttribute("src", "{require('./full-star.png')}"); 

//okay, so you've...kinda got it working...kind of

}

  };

  render() {
    return (

        <div id = "rating0">
<img onClick = {this.rate} class = "star" id = "1" src = {require('./empty-star.png')} />
<img onClick = {this.rate} class = "star" id = "2" src = {require('./empty-star.png')} />
<img onClick = {this.rate} class = "star" id = "3" src = {require('./empty-star.png')} />
<img onClick = {this.rate} class = "star" id = "4" src = {require('./empty-star.png')}/>
<img onClick = {this.rate} class = "star" id = "5" src = {require('./empty-star.png')}/>

</div>

      );
  }
}

export default Starset0;
```

The problem is, instead of stars becoming full, they simply cease to render.  They are replaced with that image-not-found icon.  Why is this?  If I replace the source attribute manually, it displays the full star.

Comment: Use `state`. Create an array of 5 booleans, initially, all set to `false`. When a star is clicked, starting from the index of the star clicked, go back until the first item and set the value to be `true` and then *setState*. Now, you might also wanna hook each item of this array to each star to determine whether you would show / hide it *in the render method*.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
"{require('./full-star.png')}"
```

to

```
{require('./full-star.png')}



"{require('./full-star.png')}" is executed as string. so its not fetching the image.
```

Answer (score 0):

Externalize require statement and use it as a variable.

Try this

```
  import React, { Component } from "react";

  class Starset0 extends Component {

    const fullStarSrc = require('./full-star.png');
    const emptyStarSrc = require('./empty-star.png');

    rate = event => {
      const { id } = event.target;

      console.log("You clicked: " + id);
      var i;

      for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        if(i <= parseInt(id)) {
          console.log("I should change the following: " + i);
          document.getElementById(i).setAttribute("src", 
  fullStarSrc);
        }
        else {
          console.log("I should change the following: " + i);
        document.getElementById(i).setAttribute("src", 
  emptyStarSrc);
        }


        //okay, so you've...kinda got it working...kind of

      }

    };

    render() {
      return (

        <div id="rating0">
          <img onClick={this.rate} class="star" id="1" src= 
 {emptyStarSrc} />
          <img onClick={this.rate} class="star" id="2" src= 
 {emptyStarSrc} />
          <img onClick={this.rate} class="star" id="3" src= 
 {emptyStarSrc} />
          <img onClick={this.rate} class="star" id="4" src= 
 {emptyStarSrc} />
          <img onClick={this.rate} class="star" id="5" src= 
 {this.emptyStarSrc} />

        </div>

      );
    }
  }

  export default Starset0;
```

Comment: If I do this it calls the variables "unexpected tokens"

Comment: Actually, if I initialize the variables before "class Starset0 extends Component" I can get it to run without errors, but the problem remains exactly the same.